# An empty array is returning though I ve pushed values to the same array inside a foreach

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have added my code below. Console.log() prints an empty array. Can anyone tell me the reason??

```
var arr = [];
stages.forEach(async(stage) => {
  const tasks = await Task.find({
    stageName: stage._id
  });
  return arr.push(tasks);  
});
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: returning a value in a forEach is useless. Also, the `find` response is asynchronous, so you cannot expect the final console log (which is executed synchronously) to know about a value that will only arrive in some future.

Comment: Consider doing something like `Promise.all(stages.map(stage => Task.find({stageName: stage._id})))`

Answer (score 0):

You're doing async.  The array won't contain elements when `console.log` runs.  Each call to your anonymous function returns a promise that you're ignoring.  If you want to make sure you have the results, you could do this:

```js
let promises = stages.map(stage => Task.find({
    stageName: stage._id
  }));

Promise.all(promises)
.then(results => {
  console.log(results);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `async/await` in `forEach` loop won't help you in this case, instead use a normal `for` loop

```js
async function execute() {
  var arr = []
  for (let stage of stages) {
    const tasks = await Task.find({
      stageName: stage._id,
    })
    return arr.push(tasks)
  }
  console.log(arr)
}

execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

loop through stages are not run asynchronously before loop console.log will print

```
const promises = _.map(stages, async (stage) => {
  const tasks = await Task.find({
    stageName: stage._id
  });
  return tasks
})
const tasks = await Promise.all(promises)
```

`lodash` async map return promise and resolve give resolve data

Comment: Why lodash? The OP does not mention this.

Comment: You can just return `Task.find({...})` from your map function, as awaiting a promise and then returning the result from an async function will just wrap the result back into a promise again. Also maybe use `Array.prototype.map()` instead

Comment: yes, indeed you can map through the array map method and make promise array. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If my guess is right,

```
async(stage) => {
 const tasks = await Task.find({
  stageName: stage._id
 });
 return arr.push(tasks);  
}
```

This code will get executed in the next event loop. so the `console.log()` gets executed immediately thus the array is `[]`
try logging `setTimeout(() => console.log(arr), 1000)` or after the task is complete